# Comment traduire l'usage anglais de la locution latine « non sequitur » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions, latin

Cette locution latine n'est, à ma connaissance, pas (ou exceptionnellement?) utilisée en français, alors qu'elle est relativement courante, en tant que substantif (*this is **a** non sequitur*), chez les anglophones¹.

A force de la rencontrer dans des contextes anglophones, j'ai intégré le concept et me retrouve parfois dans la situation de l'employer en français. Cependant, elle risque de ne rien évoquer (sauf une éventuelle connotation un peu pédante) telle quelle, et je ne sais pas comment la traduire ou la remplacer. Des idées ?

¹ je n'ai en revanche aucune idée sur leur manière de la prononcer! ...mais ce n'est pas le sujet.

Comment: Pour la prononciation anglaise voir et écouter le [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non_sequitur#Pronunciation)

Comment: Merci Laure, je n'ai pas encore le réflexe d'utiliser cette ressource, mais c'est très pratique en effet.

Comment: Tu veux désigner le procédé littéraire (souvent comique) ou l’erreur logique ?

Comment: @Edouard j'avoue que je n'avais pas songé à différencier les deux usages, même si je serais probablement plus à même de l'employer dans le contexte du procédé d'écriture. Même si tu as une réponse qui ne correspond qu'à un seul de ces deux usages, n'hésite pas à nous la partager :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/non%20sequitur) propose un « coq-à-l’âne » qui me semble ne coller qu’au procédé d’écriture. On peut vouloir modifier la phrase pour utiliser « passer du coq à l’âne » qui sera probablement mieux compris que le substantif « coq-à-l’âne ».

En matière de logique, personnellement, je pense que je conserverais « non sequitur ». Le latin ne me semble pas rare en matière de logique ou de rhétorique. À moins que ce ne soit l’anglais qui se répande dans mon vocabulaire ? C’est très possible. J’éviterais « fallacieux » car cela sous-entend une volonté de tromper alors que le « non sequitur » peut-être une simple erreur de logique.

Si tu veux vraiment l’éviter, j’utiliserais tout simplement « raisonnement inexact » ou je j’écrirais explicitement quelque chose comme « on ne peut pas en déduire cette conclusion ».

Comment: L'emploi de *non sequitur* dans la conversation courante non philosophique est à mon avis beaucoup plus rare en France qu'au Royaume-Uni ou aux USA. À moins de vouloir frimer ou paraître pédant je ne l'emploierai pas dans n'importe quelle circonstances.

Comment: +1 pour *« coq-à-l’âne »* qui sera excellent pour certains usages du terme

Comment: Chacune des réponses a apporté des éléments, mais c'est celle-ci qui m'a semblé la plus utile et complète. Merci à tous.

Answer (score 5):

*Non sequitur* est effectivement très peu employé en français. On pourrait selon les contextes et niveau de langue recherché traduire *it's a non sequitur* par :  « C'est illogique/pas logique », « c'est fallacieux », « c'est une fausse conclusion », « c'est incohérent », voire « c'est absurde ».

Comment: Bonnes remarques, notamment pour *incohérent* qui ne m'était pas venu. Ce qui me gêne, c'est que l'usage que je recherche est un substantif et non un adjectif. L'utilisation de la forme *C'est (+ adjectif)* est une manière de contourner ce problème, mais au détriment d'une certaine lourdeur, peut-être.

Comment: Autre idée à la lecture de ta réponse : à la limite, *inconséquent* n'est-il pas ici plus juste qu'*incohérent*? (à la fois plus littéral et plus proche du sens originel) On aurait alors *a non sequitur = une inconséquence*

Comment: Je pense que le « c'est... » correspond à ma façon de m'exprimer, mais je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne pourrait pas dire « une incohérence », une « une inconséquence », « un illogisme », etc...

Comment: Dans un *non sequitur*, la conclusion peut tout à fait être vraie ; seul le raisonnement est faux. Une « fausse déduction », peut-être ?

Comment: @Édouard: « Peut », c'est pour ça que je parle du contexte.

Comment: Mais, même si dans le contexte la conclusion est fausse, *non sequitur* ne signifie jamais que la conclusion est fausse, seulement que le raisonnement est faux. On peut certes prendre « fausse » au sens de « erronée » mais, à mon avis, l’ambiguïté est risquée.

Comment: À la reflexion, je me dis que si la conclusion n’était pas vraie, je dirai « une conclusion fausse », pas « une fausse conclusion ». Peut-être n’est-ce donc pas si ambigu.

Comment: @Laure (+1) Oui, les substantifs correspondants sont tout-à-fait utilisables aussi, ça me va très bien.

Answer (score 3):

De la définition de *[non sequitur](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur)*, ***fallacieux*** est le mot clef, c'est aussi le mot pivot utilisé dans ***[sophisme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisonnement_fallacieux)***.

Un retour parmi les résultats d'une recherche sur "*[Dalloz fallacieux](http://actu.dalloz-etudiant.fr/fileadmin/actualites/pdfs/OCTOBRE_2013/D1998-113.pdf)*" semble indiquer que *fallacieux* est utilisé dans les comptes-rendus, alors qu'un autre retour sur "*[Dalloz sophisme](http://www.dalloz.fr/documentation/lien?famille=revues&dochype=RECUEIL/CHRON/2013/0235)*" renverrait plutôt à la doctrine.

- Ces arguments sont *fallacieux* : ils sont contradictoires sur les point A et B et deviennent *illogiques* lorsque l'on avance l'argument C.
- L'utilisation de *sophismes* dans la plaidoirie demande une vigilance d'écoute sans faille de la part du jury.

Ceci pour une rhétorique judiciaire.

*AJOUT après commentaire*

La traduction mot à mot du latin *[non sequitur](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/non_sequitur)* « ne suit pas » oriente vers la traduction 'par défaut' de **non sens**, s'il n'y a plus de sens, on ne sait plus quoi suivre.

> - *this is a non sequitur* : c'est un non sens.

*[Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=it's%20a%20non%20sequitur&source=english)* propose des traductions liées au contexte telles qu'*absurde*, ***sans rapport***, *illogique*, ***incohérence bizarre***.

Comment: *sophisme* est une catégorie plus large dans laquelle certains usages de *non sequitur* peuvent s'inscrire, en effet, mais c'est beaucoup trop général me semble-t-il. *Fallacieux* n'est pas un substantif, et même s'il peut parfois s'appliquer à un *non sequitur*, ce n'est pas toujours le cas. Il me semble que tu as pris comme acquis une putative *intention de tromper*, qui ne me semble pas présente dans le concept à traduire.

Comment: Autre chose, un point que je n'ai pas compris : ... Dalloz ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI  Réponse complétée - Orienté par ma première recherche sur Wikipédia, j'ai lié ma recherche à celle du nom de la bibliothèque de référence du monde judiciaire.

Comment: Ah, je me disais bien que ça me disait quelque chose ce nom... ;-) merci pour tes précisions (+1).

Answer (score -1):

Est-ce qu'on pourrait traduire par "dans un autre ordre d'idées"?

Comment: Ceci ne correspond pas [à la définition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur) il me semble..

Comment: Pour lui accorder le bénéfice du doute, il faut se rappeler qu'il y a bien deux côtés de l'usage anglais auquel l'OP fait allusion : erreur de séquence logique vs. énoncé bizarrement hors sujet. On nuance parfois un tel énoncé (qui sinon enfrendrait la [« maxime de relation »](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_relation) proposée par Grice) en disant quelque chose comme « To make a non sequitur » ou « Pardon the non sequitur ». Je dirais que ce genre de concession pourrait se traduire par « dans un autre ordre d'idées ».